# Casting riffle scroll spells on multiple spell lists

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, magic, crafting

Say that I am a Wizard who has a [Riffle spell scroll](https://aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Riffle%20ScrollCantrip) containing  a spell and it was made by a Summoner who  can cast it as a different level spell, could I use it because it is a spell that is on the Wizard spell list or can I not because it was made by a different class and/or at a different spell level? Also would a Summoner crafting one use the  spell level he gets it at for the price or the level the wizard gets it as for the price RAW?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a good question, but it's made much more complicated by the *simulacrum* spell and whether or not material components are expended upon the scroll's creation or upon its use. Is there a different spell that can be used as an example instead? (And if the *simulacrum* question remains, ask that separately?) Thank your for participating and have fun!

Comment: I was using simulacrum as an example spell doesn't matter and edited accordingly.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Riffle scrolls follow the same rules as regular spell scrolls, so I *believe* that the material components bit is covered in the normal spell scroll rules.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @RevanantBacon I agree. However, I expect many folks would prefer their *simulacrum* scrolls be able to make duplicates of whatever's in front of them and supply their own components rather than the scroll only creating a duplicate of whatever "ice sculpture of the target" was used in the scroll's creation (along with the appropriate amount of powdered rubies, of course). Hence the potential for controversy.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Oohhhhh, derp, I totally wasn't even thinking of Simulacrum having a variable cost based on the copied creature. :p

Comment: The last edit leaves the question a bit weird; it uses "a spell" but still references the level difference and it says "casts can cast it" and doesn't explain how that differs from normal. Can you give it another read-over and fix the sentence structure?

Comment: oof didn't notice I've fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Spell level isn’t an inherent part of a spell—the same spell can be found at different levels on different spell lists. But it is still the same spell—so if you have a spell on your spell list, you have that spell on your spell list. If something requires that—as spell scrolls do—then you meet the requirement. The fact that the person who created the item was a different class of spellcaster, or even that they got it at a different spell level, does not matter.

(Note that having the spell on your spell list isn’t the only requirement. For example, if you are a divine spellcaster, it must be a divine scroll, and likewise for arcane. I’m only talking about the “on your list” requirement here.)

The spell’s level, for the purposes of effects that care, is whatever the creator crafted it as. So save DC, whether or not it can bypass a *globe of invulnerability*, and so on, are all set to 5th in this case, not 7th, even though for your own class the spell was 7th-level.

This also affects the item’s **cost**, because the lower spell level and lower minimum caster level means you can scribe it as a cheaper, lower-level item. This is one of the reasons why the chained summoner is so problematic, and why the nerfed, “unchained” summoner is recommended.

The fact that we are talking about a *riffle scroll* here makes no difference. *Riffle scrolls* work in almost all ways exactly the same as regular *scrolls* (the only real exception being the built-in Silent Spell effect, and of course the cost).

Comment: "Hello, yes, I would like to craft my *Scrolls*, *Wands*, and *Potions of Haste* for 2/3 the cost, thanks" said every chained summoner ever

Comment: Not aimed at your answer (but noted here because it's not an answer to the question), something to note is that spells added to riffle scrolls are required to be silent spell versions of that spell, thereby increasing the spell level of the added spell (and its caster level).